Degrees of freedom in pycalphad
I am using PyCalphad to perform equilibrium calculations for a multi-component system, but I am encountering the error "Number of degrees of freedom is not zero." I have tried several approaches to resolve this issue, but the error persists.
I am using,
phases = ['FCC_A1', 'BCC_A2']
components = ['FE', 'C', 'MN', 'SI', 'NI', 'AL', 'NB', 'VA']
and then using equilibrium function from pycalphad by passing it the .tdb file along with temperature, pressure, total moles, and the composition of all the elements.
I tried various combinations but always ended up with "Error: Number of degrees of freedom is not zero". I have tried cases when I make total degrees of freedom zero following Gibbs Phase Rule. I have also tried just making the compositional degrees of freedom zero as the source code for pycalphad.equilibrium seems to be using just the composition degrees of freedom.
I basically want to obtain the phase fractions.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Have you tried a much simpler system to begin with? Say just Al-Si with just fcc, diamond cubic, and liquid?

I have tried with just three components still same error.

They are asking for the number of dependent variables.

According to me, the mole fractions of any 6 components (since total 7 components) are independent. Also the pressure and temperature and the total moles. However, I have tried specifying all of the values but still get the same error.
